# Jquery Ajax call is sporadic

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call as below. It is working only if I run it in debug mode.

Using IE 11, use F12, put a breakpoint at $.ajax() and then it is making a call to servlet. If I refresh the browser in normal(without JavaScript debug mode) it is not getting submitted to Servlet. Any help ? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("I am here ...1");
  $.ajax({
    url: "/digitalStratagy/Greetings"        
  }).then(function(data) {
    $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
    $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
  });   
})
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I am back to coding world after long time. I just forgot. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem by adding **cache: false** setting. Please feel free to correct me if it is something else. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I am having another issue that the page is loading faster than before building the dropdown using JSTL. If I hit F5, then the drop down values are appearing. If there anyway I can hold loading the page before populating the dropdown data ? Thanks!